# Getting an The Youtube API request failed: quotaExceeded

Tags: api, quota

We've run a broadcaster awards site for the past 10 years.  It's for local broadcasters and publishers to submit entries for their state association.  Entrants can submit audio files, image files, document files, 3rd party website URLS...or for videos, submit a YouTUbe url from their own account that the judges will see played back on our embedded viewer.

This has worked great for several years.  It's called [www.bestinmedia.com](http://www.bestinmedia.com)

We've recently run into an API request failed quotaExceeded error and the url will not be added to the users account.  This started happening over the last 2 weeks near the end of one associations entry period.  We've never seen it before and nothing has changed on our site.  No settings changed.

Is this a permanent error due to some change at YouTube, or can I fix it?  I can send a video screen capture of the process and error if needed

Thanks for your time,
Tom

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Got ya.  Here is a screen cap video of the process that leads to getting the API quotaExceeded.  LMK if you need a log in to try it yourself

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/ZGXvBcP6

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved